# Como liberar conteúdo no wordpress após X dias de registro do usuário

Tags: php, wordpress, plugin-wordpress

Estou desenvolvendo uma área de membros no Wordpress, e preciso limitar o acesso de acordo com a data de registro do usuário. Eu já tenho a data de registro e já tenho a quantidade de dias que o usuário está cadastrado usando a função Diff do php.

Exemplo:

Usuário se cadastra hoje e tem acesso a página X, ele só pode ver a página Y depois de 10 Dias, caso ele tenha menos dias, exibo uma mensagem de erro e com 10 dias ou mais, eu libero a página.

Pode ser plugin, não tem problema.

Comment: você pode suar o `date('suaData', '+10 day'); e verificar com o diff novamente.

Comment: Mas como eu poderia fazer isso com mais de 10 páginas por exemplo? porque todas as páginas usam o arquivo page.php e eu preciso de dias diferentes pra cada página criada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você vai adicionar no banco a data em que o usuário se cadastrou, e criar para cada página uma validação que pega a data atual e compara com a data de cadastro.

If ($diasCadastrado > $diasParaExibir)
{
Include 'suaPagina.php';
}

Essa é a ideia básica, no seu caso basta adicionar no banco o momento em que ele acessou a determianda página